# Calculate the determinant of a given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

In a classical mechanics exercise i cannot calculate the determinant of the following matrix

$\begin{pmatrix}\left(-\omega ^2-\frac{2k}{m}\right)\: & \:\frac{k}{m}\: & \:0\: & \:0\: \\\frac{k}{m}\: & \:\left(-\omega ^2-\frac{2k}{m}\right)\: & \:\frac{k}{m}\: & \:0\: \\0\: & \:\frac{k}{m}\: & \:\left(-\omega ^2-\frac{2k}{m}\right)\: & \:\frac{k}{m}\: \\0\: & \:0\: & \:\frac{k}{m}\: & \:\left(-\omega ^2-\frac{2k}{m}\right)\end{pmatrix}$
Then it is needed to solve for $\omega$ and i cannot because it gave me $\:\frac{\left(-\omega \:^2-\frac{2k}{m}\right)^2}{\left(\frac{k}{m}\right)^2}-\frac{\left(\frac{k}{m}\right)^2}{\left(-\omega \:\:^2-\frac{2k}{m}\right)^2}=1$
Then i need also to calculate the following system:

$\begin{pmatrix}\left(-\omega ^2-\frac{2k}{m}\right)\: & \:\frac{k}{m}\: & \:0\: & \:0\: \\\frac{k}{m}\: & \:\left(-\omega ^2-\frac{2k}{m}\right)\: & \:\frac{k}{m}\: & \:0\: \\0\: & \:\frac{k}{m}\: & \:\left(-\omega ^2-\frac{2k}{m}\right)\: & \:\frac{k}{m}\: \\0\: & \:0\: & \:\frac{k}{m}\: & \:\left(-\omega ^2-\frac{2k}{m}\right)\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}A_1 \\A_2 \\A_3 \\A_4\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\: \\0\: \\0\: \\0\end{pmatrix}$

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the system as 
$$
A = 
\frac{k}{m} \overbrace{\pmatrix{
-2&1\\
1&-2&1\\
&1&-2&1\\
&&1&-2&1
}}^{\text{call this matrix } B} - \omega^2 I
$$
It suffices to calculate the characteristic polynomial $p(x) = \det(B - xI)$.  We then have
$$
\det(A) = (k/m)^4p\left(\frac{m\omega^2}{k}\right)
$$
Your system will only have a solution when $p\left(\frac{m\omega^2}{k}\right) = 0$.

---

You should find 
$$
p(x) = x^4 - 8x^3 + 21 x^2 - 20 x + 5 =(x^2 - 5x + 5)(x^2 - 3x + 1)
$$